# MongoDB take the right reference with pattern matching

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, alpakka

I am trying to insert records depends datatype to mongodb with the https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/mongodb.html api.
Let`s first take a look at the datatype:

```
  sealed trait MsgDoc {
    }

    final case class MsgPreFailure(raw: String, reasons: Chain[String]) extends MsgDoc

    final case class MsgProceed(raw: String, status: MsgStatus) extends MsgDoc


    sealed trait MsgStatus {

    }

    case object MsgSuccess extends MsgStatus

    final case class MsgFailure(reasons: Chain[String]) extends MsgStatus

    final case class MsgUnknown(reason: String) extends MsgStatus
```

For every inhabitant of `MsgDoc` sum type, I am going to create they own registry, because I would like to store on differenet collection

```
    val preFailureRegistry = fromRegistries(fromProviders(classOf[MsgPreFailure]), DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY)
    val proceedRegistry = fromRegistries(fromProviders(classOf[MsgProceed]), DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY)

    private val client = MongoClients.create("mongodb://localhost:27017")
    private val db = client.getDatabase("Message")

    private val preFailureColl = db
      .getCollection("Failure", classOf[MsgPreFailure])
      .withCodecRegistry(preFailureRegistry)


    private val proceedColl = db
      .getCollection("Proceed", classOf[MsgProceed])
      .withCodecRegistry(proceedRegistry)
```

Then let`s try to insert one record into the mongo db:

```
    Source
      .single[MsgDoc](MsgPreFailure("Test", Chain("Foo", "Foo", "Foo")))
      .runWith(MongoSink.insertOne(???))
```

As the argument to the `insertOne` method, I would like to pass either `preFailureColl` or `proceedColl` depends on the datatype(either `MsgPreFailure` or `MsgProceed`). 
In the example above, it is `MsgPreFailure`, then it should do the following call

```
    Source
      .single[MsgDoc](MsgPreFailure("Test", Chain("Foo", "Foo", "Foo")))
      .runWith(MongoSink.insertOne(preFailureColl))
```

The question is, how to pattern match within the `insertOne` method to take the right reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a stream that has two branches which are terminated with different sinks. One of the ways to achieve that is with a [`divertTo`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/divertTo.html) operator.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and let you know.